# Why is the date formatted differently when printing on frontend and backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I'm using the Javascript `new Date()` to find the current date. I'm using React.js, and on my frontend code in one of my action files, I `console.log(new Date());` and get `Thu May 02 2019 22:30:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`. When I do the same `console.log(new Date());` on the backend in one of my routes files, I get `2019-05-03T02:30:48.561Z`. Both files use Javascript and `new Date()`, so I'm confused on why the date is formatted differently in the frontend compared to the backend.

I haven't found any similar question; any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Backend ? do you mean on server side? when you rund new Date() on the backend it will take the date and time of the server, on react it will take the Date and Time of the client Machine.

Comment: backend, also javascript code, but the runtime is different

Comment: @Hosar By backend I do mean server side. That makes sense and I get why the seconds may be different, but why is the format different if they use the same Javascript `new Date()`

Comment: The JS date object can has methods for displaying in various formats. These are probably defaults for the browser JS and server side (I'm assuming it's Node.js). Try `console.log(new Date().toISOString())` on your frontend code, and `console.log(new Date().toString())` on your backend.

Comment: the date object is like that, it depends on the environment it's running. as each environment has it default settings.

Comment: @JuniusL.—the Date object itself is consistent, it's the host environment that differs. In particular, the output of *console.log* is not standardised, so when stringifying a Date, it may use the built–in *Date.prototype.toString* (whose format has been standardised recently), or any other format it choses. E.g. in StackOverflow code snippets, `console.log(date)` appears to use *toISOString* instead of *toString*.